# Simulate sending keys

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I am trying to simulate a keyboard by sending keys using keybd_event as described below.

Initially from my window load event I create a background worker and start it. This background worker, among other things, subscribe to a form keypress event if a simulation parameter is active.

I have ensured that this parameter is active so I subscribe to the winform keypress event correctly.

Also in the form I have a button to start the simulation of the keyboard. When this button is clicked "btnSimulateKeyboard_Click", I send a string that then is converted to an array of bytes and finally each byte is sent using keybd_event within a loop.

My problem is that form keypress event is never fired. Why? Isn't it the correct way to simulate sending keys?

```
namespace My.Apps.WinForms.Test
{
    public partial class MyForm: Form
    {
        #region Constructor
        public MyForm()
        {
          InitializeComponent();
        } 
        #endregion

        private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Some stuff

            _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            _worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(_worker _DoWork);
            _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(_worker _RunWorkerCompleted);
            _worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(_worker t_ProgressChanged);
            _worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void _worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            // Some stuff
            // Load parameters

            if (simulateKeyboard)
            {
               this.InitKb();
            }

            // Some stuff
        }

        private void InitKb()
        {
            this.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.MyForm_KeyPress);
        }

        private void MyForm_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            // Check key pressed
        }    

        private void btnSimulateKeyboard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SimulateKeyboardTest.SendString("abcdefg");
        }       
    }
}
```

Keyboard simulation class:

```
namespace My.Apps.WinForms.Test
{
    public static class SimulateKeyboardTest
    {
        #region DLLs Import
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);
        #endregion

        #region Constants

        public const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001;      // Key down flag
        public const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002;            // Key up flag

        #endregion

        #region Public Static Methods

        /// <summary>
        ///   Sends a string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="strChars">String to send.</param>
        public static void SendString(string strChars)
        {
            byte[] bytChars = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strChars);
            for (int i = 0; i < bytChars.Length; i++)
            { 
                KeyPress(bytChars[i]);
                KeyUp(bytChars[i]);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   Simulate a key press
        /// </summary>
        public static void KeyPress(byte keyCode)
        {
            keybd_event(keyCode, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   Simulate a key release 
        /// </summary>
        public static void KeyUp(byte keyCode)
        {
            keybd_event(keyCode, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have to call `KeyDown` before `KeyPress`? AFAIK the normal order is `KeyDown` => `KeyPress` => `KeyUp`

Comment: Sending keystrokes to control with the focus, the button you just clicked, is not useful.  A button only responds to a space, not one you ever want to send since that would never end.  The form never gets a KeyPress event when you have a control that can get the focus.  This code is just not useful and it is impossible to guess how it was intended to be useful.

Comment: @HansPassant so how can I send keys programatically to a winform form keypress event after clicking on a button?

Comment: You don't need an event when you can call the MyForm_KeyPress() method directly.  Directly calling an event handler method is not wrong, although you'd normally favor moving common code into another method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just send the keys using the winForms SendKeys.Send() method, no workers or events required.

see MSDN docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, but this has the same problem as Hans Passant commented. If I use SendKeys.Send() from the button click event, the form keypress event is never raised as the button just clicked is the current active and it has the focus.... So how to solve this?